# Получение id option

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте! Есть выпадающий список:

```
   $db = connectDB();
   $q = $db->query("SELECT `name`, `idUser` FROM `users`");
   echo '<select name="а">';
      while ($row = $q->fetch_assoc()){
      echo ("<option class='getId'  id='".$row["idUser"]."'>"  . $row["name"] . "</option>");
    }
    echo '</select>';
```

И скрипт с помощью которого нужно узнать id выбранного option:

```
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.getId').on('click', function(){
     var getId = this.id;
     alert(getId);
    })
   });
  </script>
```

Но не работает. Даже просто alert не срабатывает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На `option` элементах `onclick` срабатывать не будет. Поэтому либо привязывайтесь на событие смены элемента, либо если вам надо получать выбранный `option` - получайте его с помощью `option:selected` селектора.

Также советую не аттачить `userId` к `id` элемента. А если у вас будет 2 селекта пользователей на странице? Для таких целей придумали `dataset`. Просто закидывайте все такие данные в `data-...` аттрибуты.

```js
$('.user-select').change(function() {
  let userId = $(this).find('option:selected').data('user-id');
  console.log('Changed to user #' + userId);
});

$('.resolve-selected-user-id').click(function() {
  let userId = $('.user-select option:selected').data('user-id');
  console.log('Selected user #' + userId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='user-select'>
<option data-user-id='1'>user 1</option>
<option data-user-id='2'>user 2</option>
<option data-user-id='3'>user 3</option>
</select>

<button class='resolve-selected-user-id'>Show selected user id</button>
```

Comment: AGS17, спасибо чувак, ты крутой!

Comment: AGS17, можете подсказать как поступить в случае, когда два выпадающих списка зависят друг от друга(например: марки и модели автомобилей)

Comment: @r.mcreal при смене значений из одного списка делайте запрос на сервер за вторым списком и по получении ответа заменяйте во втором значения

Comment: AGS17, уже сделал. С помощью jquery

Comment: AGS17, а как можно поступить в случае когда нужно узнать значение всех выпадающих списков? Например: в одном списке мы выбрали марку автомобиля, а в другом модель. Теперь после нажатия на кнопку нужно получиться оба выбранных значения и занести в бд. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @r.mcreal вытягивайте первое значение,второе и отправляйте на сервер.

Comment: AGS17, вопрос каким способом?)

Comment: AGS17, может как-то в сессии хранить на стороне? Но это будет уже как-то не тру

Comment: @r.mcreal какая сессия? Получайте из первого и второго значения как показано в обработчике клика на кнопку в моем примере

Comment: AGS17,  если так,   ` $('.send').on('click', function(){
        let idBrand = $(this).find('option:selected').data('cars_brand-id');
        alert(idBrand);
    });`, то alert выводит undefined

Comment: @r.mcreal серьезно? Как вы думаете, какой элемент вы получаете через `$(this)`? У меня в примере _в обработчике клика на кнопку_ явно не так показано.

Comment: AGS17, Спасибо огромное! Я туплю капец((  Все удалось

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61556/discussion-between-r-mcreal-and-ags17).

Answer (score 0):

Вы не правильно указали селектор. Вот так было бы правильно:

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.getId').on('click', function(){
     var getId = this.id;
     alert(getId);
    })
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: Это я пропустил случайно точку. Не работает

Answer (score 0):

Вот как-то так и получаеться, через метод attr :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.getId').on('click', function() {
    var getId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(getId);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<option class="getId" id="tratatata">GetId</option>
```

Comment: Так а где у вас `option` внутри `select`?

Comment: Ваша правда, фигня ето все) надо change юзать :)

Answer (score 0):

С JavaScript у вас всё правильно, но вы неправильно указали класс. Классы, как и другие аттрибуты, беруться **только в *двойные* кавычки**. а для этого просто экранируйте их или используйте одинарные вместо двойных(второй способ лучше):

```
$db = connectDB();
$q = $db->query("SELECT `name`, `idUser` FROM `users`");
echo '<select name="а">';
  while ($row = $q->fetch_assoc()){
  echo ('<option class="getId"  id=\"".$row["idUser"]."\">"  . $row["name"] . "</option>');
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Только в **двойные**? Спорим, что в данном случае и [**с одинарными**, и **без** (если учесть, что пробелов нет)  ковычек все будет работать](http://www.wisdomweb.ru/HTML/atr.php)? :)